# Is Python list.extend() Order Presserving?

Tags: python, list

I'm wondering whether the extend function preserves the order in the two list.

```
>> list = [1, 2, 3]
>> list.extend([4, 5])
>> list
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Is extend always working like that way?

Comment: That's what `extend` means. . .

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes.

`list.extend()` just *extends* the arguments given to the end of the list.

According to the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Extend the list by appending all the items in the given list; equivalent to a[len(a):] = L.

So:

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> a[len(a):] = [4, 5]
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

By the way, don't shadow the built-in type by naming a list `list`.