# Python insert and maintain the list order without duplicate

Tags: python-3.x, list

I'm trying to extent the list by inserting the last name next to first name to create the single list. With below code I'm able to extend and remove duplicate but not able to maintain the order. Any help on how to achieve the expected output will be much appreciated

```
fname = ['John', 'Harry', 'Matt', 'Sara']
flname = ['John', 'Burns', 'Matt', 'Johnson', 'Harry', 'Ross']

#Adding below solution based on @jmd_dk
flname_iter = iter(flname)
names = []
for a in fname:
    if a not in names:
        names.append(a)
    for b in flname_iter:
        if b not in names:
            names.append(b)
            break

print(fname)
```

expected output

```
['John', 'Burns', 'Harry', 'Ross', 'Matt', 'Johnson', 'Sara']
```

current output

```
['John', 'Harry', 'Matt', 'Sara', 'Burns', 'Johnson', 'Ross']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is Python list.extend() Order Presserving?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19085713/is-python-list-extend-order-presserving). You have to reorder you list after the `extend`, but I don't see any logic in the sorting of your expected output

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the problem correctly, you can do it by having the inner iteration over `flname` remembering where it was the last time around. We can do this by explicitly constructing an iterator out of `flname`:

```py
fname = ['John', 'Harry', 'Matt', 'Sara']
flname = ['John', 'Burns', 'Matt', 'Johnson']

flname_iter = iter(flname)
names = []
for a in fname:
    if a not in names:
        names.append(a)
    for b in flname_iter:
        if b not in names:
            names.append(b)
            break

print(names)
```

Comment: your approach helped but somehow 'Matt' is repeated on final list
`['John', 'Burns', 'Harry', 'Matt', 'Matt', 'Johnson', 'Sara']`. I tried adding few additonal data and it stilled gave dup 'Matt'. changed the value of Matt and tired no luck

Comment: @Qzia88 What about now?

Comment: your solution helped but failed to maintain the order if I add harry lastname like `flname = ['John', 'Burns', 'Matt', 'Johnson', 'Harry', 'Ross'] ` it printed put as `['John', 'Burns', 'Harry', 'Matt', 'Johnson', 'Sara', 'Ross']`, any thought how to maintain the order during this case

Comment: any thought for above use case

Comment: @Qzia88 I don't quite know exactly what you want/expect. Could you update the question with a general example, the solution of which will be sufficient to solve any values of `fname` and `flname`?

Comment: I updated the question and expected output,  having issue with `['Harry', 'Ross']` which is new output expected, John and matt worked as expeceted but if Harry is part of flname at the end of the list it didnt store in expected order

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why `'Ross'` should go in the middle of the list. Can you expand on what you are trying to do?

Comment: Got two lists where first name is part of fname (full list that contain all records) and flname is another list that contain subset of lastname along with first name. I'm trying to merge into single and place lastname adjacent to first name.

Comment: I don't get it. What makes `'Ross'` come before `'Matt'`?